# How to stop office 365 word from converting pdf from graphic to text?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office

I'm using word from the windows store and it keeps converting all my pdf graphs into text. How to stop it from using ORC and just show up the pdf as graphs?

Comment: How are you opening the PDFs? When you open a PDF in Word it will make best effort to convert because Word is designed to edit documents, and is not designed to be a PDF viewer. If you just wish to view PDFs you should not be using Word/